# How to stop github from modifying my files (in workflow)?

Tags: git, github, workflow, github-actions, carriage-return

On github.com, I have a little 6-byte file `hello.txt` consisting of "hello" and a `newline`:<sup>1</sup>

[image]

In an Ubuntu-18 workflow with `runs-on: ubuntu-18.04`, we have:

[image]

But on Windows with `runs-on: windows-2019`, there is miraculously an extra byte:<sup>2</sup>

[image]

How do I get rid of this extra byte?

---

**Update:** After studying [James'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4877147/) quick answer, I opted for a one-line `.gitattributes` file in the directory where my `hello.txt` was located:

```
* -text
```

That directory consists of test data only.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>  I do not know why GitHub drops the `.txt` extension, but I am an newbie.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup>  We can all assume the extra byte is a `carriage-return`.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line ending handling can be configured in quite a few different ways.

I'm pretty sure on Windows when you install git, there's a popup where it asks you how you want to handle CRLF's, but it's been a while since I did a fresh install.

Check out the official docs here on how you can configure it: https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings

From the Docs on the .gitattributes options:

---

- `text=auto` Git will handle the files in whatever way it thinks is best. This is a good default option.
- `text eol=crlf` Git will always convert line endings to `CRLF` on checkout. You should use this for files that must keep `CRLF` endings, even on OSX or Linux.
- `text eol=lf` Git will always convert line endings to `LF` on checkout. You should use this for files that must keep `LF` endings, even on Windows.
- `binary` Git will understand that the files specified are not text, and it should not try to change them. The binary setting is also an alias for `-text -diff`.

---

Comment: Thank you--this worked. Of course, it took a while for me to read/understand the git documentation. To minimise any change in behaviour, I opted for a one-line `.gitattributes` file in the directory where my `hello.txt` was located: `* -text`, since that directory consisted of test data only.